# Is there any way to have a reset button in the SSRS parameter window?

Tags: reporting-services, button, report, reset

Is there any way to have a reset button in the SSRS parameter window?

Answer (score 3):

Users can reset the parameters by clicking the "Refresh" button in the web browser.

Answer (score 2):

No, or i haven't heard how to do it. But you can simulate it.

One way to do this is to create a textbox that has an action set to jump to itself. You can or jump to the default values, or jump to itself with some parameters already assigned.

Comment: But is it possible to have a reset action button?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the ReportViewer.aspx...

I came across this article on how to do it but didn't try it as I was only looking into whether it can be done/has been done before and need confirmation before I can develop it:

https://github.com/MagnusJohansson/CustomSSRSReportViewer